# Quick way of copying individual files to desktop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, shortcuts

In my job I regularly have to copy individual files from various parts of the file system to my desktop (or wherever - a central location) before getting uploaded into a CMS. This is using Windows Explorer on Windows 7.

Is there a quicker way to do this than just:

- Select file, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You could simply open your working folder and the folder where the Files are to be, say cached, next to each other by dragging the explorer windows to the left respectively right screen edge.

In the left window you can then browse through the folders and look for the files, which you can then simply drag-and-drop over to the right folder.

By holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> before you release the mouse button the file is copied instead of moved.

Comment: Strg? What is that Key?

Comment: Ctrl of course, sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

If a possible solution may involve a mouse, you can right-click on a file and select *Send to location* and then *Desktop*. This creates a link though, not a copy of the file, so I don't know if it is applicable for you.